# Expressões regulares, diferença entre [-] e -

Tags: regex

Estou trabalhando com algumas expressões regulares e me deparei com o seguinte caso:

```
string pattern = @"^.{2,9}[-].{4}[-].{4}$";
string pattern = @"^.{2,9}-.{4}-.{4}$";
```

Gostaria de entender, qual a diferença de utilizar o hifén entre `[-]` ou somente  `-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os parênteses rectos (colchetes `[]`) servem para especificar listas de caracteres para validar (match). Nesse caso não tem diferença por que só está a especificar apenas um carácter `-`

Porém quando utilizado com dois ou mais caracteres, ele especifica uma lista, por exemplo, uma lista que faz match a caracteres entre 1 e 5 inclusive: `[1-5]`

Outro exemplo seria uma lista de `a` a `z`: `[a-z]`